# zend, doctrine, multiple entities to one

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

After many tries I was able to come up with something.

I can see now in my User entity other Entities properties but not their values.

I have added to my User Entity :

```
    /**
         * @OneToOne(targetEntity="UserCoaches")
         * @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
         */
private $coaches;
```

I am getting this:

```
[coaches:Entities\Users:private] => __PHP_Incomplete_Class Object
        (
            [__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name] => Proxies\__CG__\Entities\UserCoaches
            [__isInitialized__] => 
            [id] => 
            [user_id] => 
            [coach_id] => 
            [date_created] => 
            [date_active_from] => 
            [date_active_to] => 
        )
```

Do I have to "initialize" something or?

My original question follows >>>>>>>>>

> I just need you guys to point me to right direction. I do not need
>   ready to use solution.
>
> I have three entities.
>
> 1. User
>
>    - id
>    - firstname
>    - lastname
> 2. UserPlan
>
>    - id
>    - plan_id
>    - user_id
>    - active_to
> 3. Plans
>
>    - id
>    - plan_name
>
> How can I make methods from UserPlan and Plans to be visible in User
>   entity.
>
> So instead of searching UserPlans and Plans for user_id and plan_id I
>   can have something like:
>
> ```
> $user = new User entity
>
> echo $user->getPlanId().$user->getPlanName();
> ```

Comment: The right direction is to read [the docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html)

Comment: That is the right place to start.  If your schema's complexity grows a lot, you might consider trying to reverse engineer those relationships.  [Doctrine tools#reverse engineer](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#reverse-engineering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this error.

```
In my Auth class I changed from Session Auth to NonPersistent Auth.
```

Thank you google.

Issue resolved.